# Counting an integer's divisors without just enumerating them (or estimating if not possible)?

Tags: algorithm, math, integer, integer-division, number-theory

Is it possible to count the divisors an integer has without just checking each one up to `sqrt(n)`?  If not, is there at least a way to *estimate* or *approximate* how many divisors there are?

For example, 28 has six divisors (1, 2, 4, 7, 14, 28).  15 has four (1, 3, 5, 15).  I want to, say, figure out how many divisors 242134575355654335549798955848371716626563756785 has, without counting all the way up to that (or at the very least make a guess and take it from there).

Comment: Can you also include some examples?

Comment: [Integer Factorization Algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Integer_factorization_algorithms)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming but about mathematics.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I would argue that the mathematical aspect is "how many divisors are there" and that counting them efficiently is more about programming (that, yes, uses mathematical insight).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen What kind of examples are you looking for?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark, would you rather I move this to CS stack exchange?

Comment: If you think your question would be on-topic at that site then go right ahead and ask it there.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark OK, I'll do so and close (or delete; which is preferred?) this question.

Comment: I think the preferred approach is to have it migrated over.  But it looks like it's too late now: http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/49532

Answer (score 2):

If the prime factorisation of a number is known

```
N = p1^e1 * p2^e2 * ... * pn^en
```

the number of divisors is `(e1+1)*(e2+1)* ... *(en+1)`

For example 242134575355654335549798955848371716626563756785 = 5 * 48426915071130867109959791169674343325312751357 has 4 divisors

the number one higher 242134575355654335549798955848371716626563756786 = 2 * 101203 * 757790982862309619 * 1578643235504300177689649 has 16 divisors.

There are algorithms available that find the prime factorisation of a number much faster than trial division up to `sqrt(n)`. For big numbers it will still take a while ...

Comment: But, again, the thing is how to get prime factorisation at first hand!

Comment: If there are quite a few small factors, prime factorization will go quickly.  (Every divisor you find cuts down the problem size).  It's only numbers that turn out to be prime, or the product of large primes, that take a lot of time.  Your answer implies that there isn't any trick for counting the divisors without finding them.  Are you fairly sure that there is no known algorithm?  And if so, do you know if it's been proven that there isn't one?  I mean, I don't think there is one, but I'm not a number theorist at all and there's tons of stuff I don't know. :P

Comment: @PeterCordes of course one can never be sure there is no trick, and I am not aware of a proof that none exists.

Answer (score -1):

There is way to factorization a number faster than sqrt(N) but if the n <=10^7 condition is true.The way uses Eratosthenes sieve.[Here](http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/7262) is a good explanation which also I learnt from. You can ask me for clarification.

Comment: That's actually not true, there are ways to factorize faster.

Comment: You say there are ways to do it faster than logN or faster than sqrt(n) and the n<=10^7 condition has not to be true ?

Comment: Faster than sqrt(N), the n<=10^7 condition doesn't make much sense, that would force even the worst possible algorithm to become constant time.

Comment: Uhm I usually hang out in competitive programming sites and I added that condition for make the algorithm run in 1s and not make it use much memory as a habit. Let's just remove the condition and say there is a nlogn way for factorization a number. Are we OK now :D